# Erlang and websockets

Tags: erlang, websocket

Some time ago I found Joe Armstrong's example on Erlang and websocket, but I couldn't get it work.

I fixed an error and a couple of warnings in the Erlang code but with Apache I wasn't able to get a good result.

Can anybody give me some hints with a really simple example? Do I need to put the web page with the JavaScript inside the Apache directory as for normal PHP files?

Comment: It is rather hard giving any good advice, the vagueness of the question in mind. There are three parts: 1. The Erlang code, 2. The javascript code, 3. Apache and its configuration. You may want to break up the problem and get specific help for each one.

Comment: yes you are right, i was looking for a really simple example of both webpage and erlang...as in joe's example

Answer (score 8):

Joe's websocket example is outdated and relies on an obsolete version of the protocol. Up-to-date browsers use a more recent version (draft-00)

As of today, a nice erlang implementation is available from misultin. Tested and compatible with current browsers:

https://github.com/ostinelli/misultin/blob/master/src/misultin_websocket.erl

Comment: Misultin has been shut down -- and thats a shame, it was a nice framework.

Answer (score 8):

The [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org) webserver provides a websocket implementation. I also wrote a behaviour to simplify the writing of ws-based applications. It's part of my Erlang tools (well, the first one in fact):

https://github.com/schemeway/erlang-tools

Answer (score 3):

I found the [SockJS-Erlang](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-erlang) library to work wonderfully well. Best of all it supports fallback transports if websockets are not available. It uses [Cowboy](https://github.com/extend/cowboy) (although an older version) as the underlying server which is nice because it is easy to integrate with. [This escript](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-erlang/blob/master/examples/cowboy_echo.erl) and [this HTML page](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-erlang/blob/master/examples/echo.html) will give you a working demo you can play around with.

here is an annotated example:

```
start_link(_) ->
    application:start(sockjs),
    application:start(cowboy),

    % generate a SockJS handler
    SockjsState = sockjs_handler:init_state(
                    <<"/browser_socket">>, fun handle_client/3, state, []),

    % build the dispatch routes for Cowboy integrating the SockJS handler
    Routes = [{'_',  [{[<<"echo">>, '...'],
                       sockjs_cowboy_handler, SockjsState}]}],

    % start the cowboy server
    cowboy:start_listener(http, 100,
                          cowboy_tcp_transport, [{port,     8081}],
                          cowboy_http_protocol, [{dispatch, Routes}]),

% called when a new client connects
handle_client(Conn, init, state) -> {ok, state};

% called when data is received 
handle_client(Conn, {recv, Data}, state) ->
  % reply to client
  Conn:send(Data);

% called when connection is closed
handle_client(_Conn, closed, state) -> {ok, state}.
```

My advice regarding Apache would be to use HAProxy for your WebSocket connections and Apache for serving Javascript and PHP.